# How do I find the diagonal matrix of this general matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Consider the $2k\times 2k$-matrix $$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
0& \frac{1}{k}& \dots& \frac{1}{k}& \frac{1}{k}& 0& \dots& 0\\
\frac{1}{k-1}& 0& \dots& \frac{1}{k-1}& 0& 0& \dots& 0\\
\vdots\\
\frac{1}{k-1}& \frac{1}{k-1}& \dots& 0& 0& 0& \dots& 0\\
\frac{1}{k}& 0& \dots& 0& 0& \frac{1}{k}& \dots& \frac{1}{k}\\
0& 0& \dots& 0& \frac{1}{k-1}& 0& \dots& \frac{1}{k-1}\\
\vdots\\
0& 0& \dots& 0& \frac{1}{k-1}& \frac{1}{k-1}& \dots& 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Here we have zero on the diagonal, the first and $(k+1)$-th row have row elements $\frac{1}{k}$ and all other rows $\frac{1}{k-1}$.

How do I find the diagonal matrix of $A$? I know that one must find the eigenvalues, but how do I do that for this $2k\times 2k$-matrix?

**Edit (my attempts):**
I know that the determinant of a matrix with values $a_{ij}$ is given by
$$\det(A)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{2k}a_{ij}A_{ij}$$
where $A_{ij}$ is the determinant of matrix $A$ with the $i$-th row and $j$-th column left out multiplied by $(-1)^{i+j}$.
I see that we have a lot of zeros and thus many terms will drop out, however I don't see how I can do this in a neat, concise manner.

**Edit (further explanation on the matrix):**
The right upper square matrix and left lower square matrix are fully zero, except for $a_{1,k+1}=a_{k+1,1}=\frac{1}{k}$.
The other two square matrices have zero only on the diagonal, the first and $(k+1)$-th row have row elements $\frac{1}{k}$ and all other rows $\frac{1}{k-1}$.

So each row sums up to $1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: What Jose Carlos wrote, and also: it is not clear how your matrix is defined. How are the "jumps" ... defined, what are the gaps, etc.?

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you for notifying me of what is not clear, please see my edit.